# Possbile to create single OS image for different computer manufacturers?

Tags: windows-7, images

I have to deal with setting up many new HP and Dell computers with basic settings and software for users(Windows 7 Pro 64-bit). I know I can create an image with pre-installed software and deploy it on computers thanks to tools like sysprep.

But... can I create an image that will work on Dell and HP, or do I have to create the image for both manufacturers?

Both would have the same settings and software installed(Office, PDF reader, chrome and so on). Computers vary in model numbers and sometimes I might get Dell or HP. Also, taking into account that both have their own pre-installed software such as recovery(partition), backup, diagnostics, support center, driveguard, and so on which I always keep just in case.

What do you think? Can I do it with 1 universal image or will I need 2 images due to difference in pre-installed software or another drawback?

Comment: May depend on what tool you are using for the "image".  If you can build the drivers separately, you may be able to approach this.

Comment: @uSlackr There's a DISM UI.exe I use, it allows you to "splitstream" drivers into it. HP and Dell usually have these driver packs you can download so I guess I would use those. But that probably means that I either have to keep separate image for each different Dell and HP model or have 1 for each but include all possible drivers for all models I have set up which means the image will grow a lot.

Comment: You'll also need to individualize some data, such as OS license ID and key.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Windows will detect any changes in hardware, so even if you install an image and boot it up on a different computer, most of the time Windows will be able to detect the new hardware and install related drivers. I have seen some exceptions, but as a general rule this should in fact work.

You problem is if you want to keep pre-installed software. If you re-image the machine, you wipe everything off of it. So if you a have any HP software on the machine, you will lose it. You'll then have to re-install it manually unless your image has it, in which case even your non-HP machines will have the software. This is also true for specific drivers that you would need which are not included in Windows.

So it all comes down to, can you maintain different images for different brands and do you want to maintain them. Or do you prefer to not have the brand specific software in the image and only have one for all your machines.

Comment: I would say using Windows Search to find and install drivers is not an option in this case. I'm starting to think that I would need an image for every different model of HP and Dell at this point as drivers will be different. Pre-installed software is a must, but it's already pre-installed anyways so it's not a problem and I would just include that in the image. Manual install is not an option. I'd really prefer to keep specific pre-installed software and driver, so I'm beginning to realize that I'd need to maintain a separate for every model of Dell and HP I come across. I don't mind I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to go around this sort of problem unless you go away from images and use something like a configuration management software. Config management is very useful for big environments as it is costly to implement and maintain but when you have lots of machines, the cost pays off. How big is the environment you are maintaining?

Comment: Anywhere from 5-25 computers/laptops, different companies. But that's fine, imaging still looks attractive to me even I have to maintain lots of images. My main goal is to save time and cut the process where I have to go through Window's OOBE, installing pdf viewer reader, java, office suite and so on every time which takes up hours. Popping an image into the system and going from that is much faster IMO. And if I have to reinstall a corrupted system again I would have an image ready.

Comment: Yeah, so that's not big enough to invest in config management software. The other option you could look at is scripting the installation of different programs and configs. You could just run the script afterwards on the machines.